# Tag Synonym Request: Dell Tags

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Right now, we have [dell](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/dell) (1643), [dell-vostro](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/dell-vostro) (60), [dell-mini-10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/dell-mini-10) (17), [dell-studio-xps-16](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/dell-studio-xps-16) (10) and [dell-mini-9](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/dell-mini-9) (8).

Since those tags, except for the [dell](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/dell) tag, barely have any questions, it doesn't really make sense to keep them. If they were more popular, like the MacBook tag, then it would be useful for organization, but it seems like overkill at this point.

I propose either creating a new tag, [dell-laptop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/dell-laptop) (and maybe also a [dell-desktop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/dell-desktop) tag) and merging the 4 tags into it, or just merging everything into [dell](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/dell) (1643 isn't very much in the first place, so it could work).

Hopefully, I've done this request right.

Comment: I think one dell tag should be enough, same as with the ASUS one. The other ones have almost no questions anyway.

Comment: @MarkKirby Well, Dell does something similar to ASUS in terms of hardware, since they also make Chromebooks. My argument for this would be about the same as my answer on Thomas's post. We might need a `dell-chromebook` tag. We might also benefit from `dell-laptop` and `dell-desktop`, but I don't know, since they don't exist, and we can't really tell how many Dell questions are laptops and desktops.

Comment: This is my argument with masi, we don't need those because `dell` + `chromebook` achieves the same thing, while also allowing the tags to be non specific and flexible. Do you see? We don't need `dell-laptop` because `dell` + `laptop` already exists and is the same. You can have five tags, that is plenty to narrow it down.

Comment: That's a good point. But I think we still need `chromebox` to be specific if we ever run into it :p\

Comment: Personally, I don't see what manufacturer tags gets us. It's not as if we get a guarantee of specific hardware with it. Even dell + laptop doesn't tell me what chipset it has so I ignore them for the most part.